# When to use <div> <article> and <p>together, and how many tags are too many?

Tags: html, tags

Say you want to create a page with 3 pieces of text, 3 photos, 1 (unordered) list...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <article>
    <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
   </article>
   <img src="">
  </div>
  <div>
   <article>
    <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
   </article>
   <ul>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
   </ul>
   <img src="">
  </div>
  <div>
   <article>
    <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
   </article>
   <img src="">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Would the above make sense? i.e. is it too much to use `<article>, <div>, and <p>` tags together? When would it make sense, and when can I just go with `<p>` only - is it a matter of being able to easier style with CSS if you have more tags, or also about the structure/readability of my code?

As you may have guessed, I'm very new to creating sites and don't have good intuition with this stuff yet. Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: I think you don't need to wrap the article tags with divs. More infos about article tags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article

Comment: @Luckyfella thank you, and what if the article and img go together - do I make the img part of the article element, or can i use a div on the two then (also I understand the more tags i use the more negative the effect on rendering too btw. right)?

Comment: If the image is related to the other content of your article then it's the right place for it

Comment: @Luckyfella thank you! Final question then please: what would need to change in this document for me to actually need to use a div here - if I can group everything related to one article in the article element itself, what is the point of divs? Cheers!

Comment: @myself or I can just read about it myself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div :D thank you anyway, take care!